# Mocha Test is not passing

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mocha.js

I created a function here with assert testing:

```
function renderInventory(arr) { 
  var str = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].shoes.length; j++){
       str += arr[i].name + ', ' + arr[i].shoes[j].name + ', ' + arr[i].shoes[j].price + '\n';
    }
  }
  return str;

}

var currentInventory = [{
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [{
        name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up',
        price: 1000
    }, {
        name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up',
        price: 1100
    }, {
        name: 'plain beige suede moccasin',
        price: 950
    }, {
        name: 'plain olive suede moccasin',
        price: 1050
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [{
        name: 'red leather laced sneakers',
        price: 800
    }, {
        name: 'black leather laced sneakers',
        price: 900
    }]
}];


var actual = renderInventory(currentInventory);
var expected = "Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled black low-top lace-up, 1000" + '\n' +
"Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled green low-top lace-up, 1100" + '\n' +
"Brunello Cucinelli, plain beige suede moccasin, 950" + '\n' +
"Brunello Cucinelli, plain olive suede moccasin, 1050" + '\n' +
"Gucci, red leather laced sneakers, 800" + '\n' +
"Gucci, black leather laced sneakers, 900";

function assertrenderInventory(actual, expected, testName){
  if(actual === expected){
    console.log('passed');
  }else{
    console.log('FAILED [' + testName + '] Expected "' + actual + '" to be "' + expected + '"');
  }
}

assertrenderInventory(actual, expected, 'testing renderInventory');
```

Basically what this does is that it get the `designer name` and `shoe name` with it's `price` all in one line by iterating through the array. But for some reason no matter how I tried to do the testing it still failed and there is a 'split' error on the mocha test.

Here's the mocha test:

```
describe('render inventory', function() {
  it('renders_first_line_correctly', function() {
    var inventory = [
      {
        name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
        shoes: [
          {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
          {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
          {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
          {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Gucci',
        shoes: [
          {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
          {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
        ]
      }
    ];

    var actual = renderInventory(inventory).split('\n');
    var expected = 'Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled black low-top lace-up, 1000';
    expect(actual[0]).toBe(expected);
  });

  it('renders_second_line_correctly', function() {
    var inventory = [
      {
        name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
        shoes: [
          {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
          {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
          {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
          {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Gucci',
        shoes: [
          {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
          {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
        ]
      }
    ];

    var actual = renderInventory(inventory).split('\n');
    var expected = 'Gucci, black leather laced sneakers, 900';
    expect(actual.pop()).toBe(expected);
  });
});
```

Any idea what should I do to pass the test here?

You can check my codes here: https://jsbin.com/zeviponeda/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0):

you'r renderInventory appends '\n' to the end line also but your expected does not end with '\n'; the actual expected should be

```
var expected = "Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled black low-top lace-up, 
1000" + '\n' +
"Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled green low-top lace-up, 1100" + '\n' +
"Brunello Cucinelli, plain beige suede moccasin, 950" + '\n' +
"Brunello Cucinelli, plain olive suede moccasin, 1050" + '\n' +
"Gucci, red leather laced sneakers, 800" + '\n' +
"Gucci, black leather laced sneakers, 900" + '\n';
```

for the same reason actual.pop() results in empty string